# How to convert a Bitmap into hex data

Tags: java, android, bitmap, hex, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I'm trying to convert an image into hexadecimal data for a http POST. On the iOS version I achieved this in 2 minutes with one line of code using UIImageJPEGRepresentation.

I have spent 2 days trying to achieve the same in Java with a Bitmap image but I just can't work it out.

I've converted the bitmap into a Byte Array using:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

I don't know what to do next. I've tried writing my own hexadecimal converter based on other SO answers but have been unable to achieve the extremely simple task that it was in objective-c.

Hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: Base64 converter is what you need to look for

Comment: The server doesn't accept Base64 encoding. I need the raw hex data like I got in objective-c.